# Maven warnings - not very clear

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I have the following maven file. The build goes through; but with warnings, that I am not able to understand why:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-5-basics</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>junit-5-basics</name>
    <description>Code accompanying the JUnit 5 Basics course on Java Brains (javabrains.io)</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <dependency-check-maven.version>7.3.0</dependency-check-maven.version>
        <sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.html</sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>
        <sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.json</sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>
        <sonar.dependencyCheck.summarize>true</sonar.dependencyCheck.summarize>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                              
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals><goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals><goal>report</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
                
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>json</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>check</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get the following warnings:

> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
> io.javabrains:junit-5-basics:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
> 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found
> duplicate declaration of plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin @ line
> 76, column 15 [WARNING]  [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix
> these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
> [WARNING]  [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no
> longer support building such malformed projects. [WARNING]  [WARNING]
> The artifact org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.1.2184 has
> been relocated to
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.1.2184:
> SonarQube plugin was moved to SonarSource organisation [INFO]

On line 76, In fact there is no duplication of groupId:artifactId s far  I respected the instructions if I am not mistaken. Also, not sure why I have

> [WARNING] The artifact org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar

as nothing is mentioned in the pom file about codehaus. This build is run in Azure pipeline maven build

I applied mistakenly the  mvn help:effective-pom on the loal and not the one in the repo.

Here is the correct effective POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-5-basics</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>junit-5-basics</name>
    <description>Code accompanying the JUnit 5 Basics course on Java Brains (javabrains.io)</description>
    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.html</sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <dependency-check-maven.version>7.3.0</dependency-check-maven.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.json</sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>
    <sonar.dependencyCheck.summarize>true</sonar.dependencyCheck.summarize>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\main\resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\test\resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target</directory>
    <finalName>junit-5-basics-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                <format>html</format>
                <format>json</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>json</format>
            </formats>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
                <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
                <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
            <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
            </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Is the posted POM file the real pom file you are using? Apart from using junit jupiter old version and using surefire-plugin in a version which does not support junit jupiter etc. ?

Comment: I recommend running `mvn help:effective-pom` and take a look what the produced pom looks like

Comment: It is the real POM. So @khmarbaise, as I am not an expert in java and inherited this pipeline from another persomn, what should be the shape of the PO or how it should be updated? Thanks

Comment: Here the effectif poip

Comment: Which Java versions, Maven version etc. do you use? Please post the *the full* and complete pom file otherwise it's impossible to help...

Answer (score -1):

Tried the POM file in pipeline, when using the `jacoco-maven-plugin` version `0.8.9-SNAPSHOT`, we have to enable `snapshots` for the plugin Repositories.
[image]

But, when running the pipeline, it failed with the following error message due to  the POM for `org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.9-SNAPSHOT` is missing, no dependency information available.

```
Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.9-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.9-SNAPSHOT in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

[image]

However, it works after changing the plugin version to `<version>0.8.8</version>`. The following POM for your reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-5-basics</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>junit-5-basics</name>
  <description>Code accompanying the JUnit 5 Basics course on Java Brains (javabrains.io)</description>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.html</sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <dependency-check-maven.version>7.3.0</dependency-check-maven.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.json</sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>
    <sonar.dependencyCheck.summarize>true</sonar.dependencyCheck.summarize>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target</directory>
    <finalName>junit-5-basics-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>@{argLine} -more -arguments</argLine>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <formats>
                <format>html</format>
                <format>json</format>
              </formats>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>json</format>
          </formats>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\Workspace-Eclipse-Junit\junit-5-basics-course\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Andy after activating debugging in azure pipeline I discovered the following in 2023-01-03T11-41-45_191.dumpstream file

# Created at 2023-01-03T11:41:45.603
Unrecognized option: -more

I removed 

<configuration>
          <argLine>@{argLine} -more -arguments</argLine>
        </configuration>
  
pipeline went through but with exact same errors and un clear earnings as with my original POM